# extjs mvc navigation

Tags: extjs, navigation

I am using extjs mvc . I have 8 views  to display . there is a dependency on each view.
I wanted to know how to navigate from view to view in forward as well as backward direction.
suggest me i need to use multiple controllers or one.

Comment: what do you mean by navigate? are you changing tabs or something?

Comment: i need to go from search page to results,from results to result detail like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggested to choose a single controller approach. Let's call it NavigationController. 
The main advantage of this approach is that you separate your navigation logic and lock it in one place. It's easier to maintain and find needed coded in future.

However it's just my opinion.

Example:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.controller.NavigationController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'view1 button[text="View Search Results"]': {
                click: this.onViewSearchResults
            },
            'view2 button[text="View Search Details"]': {
                click: this.onViewSearchResultDetails
            }
            //....
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i am new to extjs.Please share any example code.

Comment: how to render the view in onViewSearchResults method.Please share any example. What about previous is it in chache ?                                                      as i tried  var resultspanel = Ext.widget('searchResultsPanel');
    Ext.getCmp('searchID').insert(0,Ext.getCmp('searchresults')); this but it is not working backward .

Comment: try Ext.getView('yourView').create(); Then add it where you need.